# What is the Perl equivalent of this Java snippet? (Java explanation in Perl terms)

Tags: java, perl, moose

Can anybody help me "translate" this java snippet into perl/Moose terms?. Trying understand java object-syntax/logic and I know only perl.

EDIT based on comments: The snippet is coming form the xwiki package - http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/DevGuide/WritingComponents...
It is too big for analyze, so what about the remaining of the code? Is possible (for the explanation only - ignore the @lines?  What is the general meaning of the '@something'?

```
@Component("hello")
public class HelloWorldScriptService implements ScriptService
{
    @Requirement
    private HelloWorld helloWorld;

    public String greet()
    {
        return this.helloWorld.sayHello();
    }
}
```

Looking for something like the next perl fragment, but have no idea about "@Component, @Requirement - etc :(

```
package HelloWorldScriptService;
use Moose;
sub greet {
    return $self->
}
```

Exists some docs where java is explained with perl-ish terms? (at least, some basics)

Comment: Annotations @Component and @Requirement are not part of the java libraries. In order to transcode you'll have to see what they are supposed to do. They seem like Spring annotations if it helps.

Comment: @Component might be spring, but @Requirement isn't.  Agreed that you need to tell us where those annotations are coming from!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not sure about the @Component, but here's some more:

```
package HelloWorld;
use Moose;

sub say_hello {
   print "Hello";
}

1;

package HelloWorldScriptService;
use Moose;

has 'hello_world' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'HelloWorld' );

# TODO - will need to instantiate the hello_world object somewhere...

sub greet {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return $self->hello_world->say_hello();
}

1;
```

since helloWorld is a private attribute in the original, you might want to prepend the name 'hello_world' with an underscore (and add init_args => undef) - this doesn't enforce privacy like Java but does show to anyone looking at the code that it's conceptually private (and prevents setting on new())

Comment: You can use BUILD to instatiate: `sub BUILD { my $self = shift; $self->hello_world(HelloWorld->new); }`

Answer (score 3):

These annotations are metadata for some [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) framework (it looks like XWiki uses its own dependency injection support, and these annotations are used by it).

When this class is used on its own, they don't have any particular meaning. But when it's used inside a DI container, `@Requirement` indicates that the value of `helloWorld` is to be injected by the container, and `@Component` indicates that the class itself can be injected into other components.